# soademo - Deploy the SelectManufacturer BPEL process using Ant 

Tags: web-services, soap, soa, soap-client

I am trying to work through the Oracle SOAEssential Tutorial and want to deploy the SelectManufacturer bpel project but the project does not deploy successfulluy because of the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\labs\SOAEssentials\SelectManufacturer\build.xml:173: A problem occurred while          
establishing a connection to the BPEL Server.
Please make sure the server is running on host "localhost", port "8888".
```

The bpel control server is running on the same port but I can't figure out why there is problem with the port. I need to find a way to verify the port but am not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the IPV6 protocol needs to be disabled as it conflicts with deploying the bpel process.

Secondly, in the build.properties file of the project, I uncommented the following line since it is my actual home rather than the default platform=ias_10g.

```
#platform=oc4j_10g
```

and comment the following

```
platform=ias_10g
```